# Make getopt optionally accept an argument without showing error

Tags: bash, getopt

I'm trying to make the getopt to optionally accept an argument. For example, based on the code below:

```
#!/bin/bash
short_opts="e:"

options=$(getopt  -o "${short_opts}" -- "$@")
retval=$?

if [[ "${retval}" != 0 ]]; then
  echo "Invalid option"
  exit 1
fi

eval set -- "${options}"

enable_value=false
while true; do
  option="$1"
  case "${option}" in
  -e)
    enable_value=$2
    shift 2
    echo "enable is: ${enable_value}"
    ;;
  --)
    shift
    break
    ;;
  -*)
    echo "invalid"
    exit 1
    ;;
  *)
    break
    ;;
  esac
done
```

In the above code, I can run an argument `-e` like this

`./script.sh -e true`

Then it will print out this output

`enable is: true`

Now what I want is, to use the same option -e without any argument

`./script.sh -e`

and my expected output should be this:

`enable is: true`

but when I use -e without argument, it will complain that it needs an argument. I understand what is going on because I should put the symbol `e:` so that it can accept the argument.

So, what I have done is I try to add another `e:` argument for the short options like below:

`short_opts="e,e:"`

and obviously it did not work

In my code above in order to be able to pass `-e` alone it is easy to change the above code to be like this (only a small change):

```
#!/bin/bash
short_opts="e"

options=$(getopt  -o "${short_opts}" -- "$@")
retval=$?

if [[ "${retval}" != 0 ]]; then
  echo "Invalid option"
  exit 1
fi

eval set -- "${options}"

enable_value=false
while true; do
  option="$1"
  case "${option}" in
  -e)
    enable_value=false
    shift
    echo "enable is: ${enable_value}"
    ;;
  --)
    shift
    break
    ;;
  -*)
    echo "invalid"
    exit 1
    ;;
  *)
    break
    ;;
  esac
done
```

But, based on my 2 codes above, is there a way to make `getopt` accept both argument and empty argument (by just passing an option `-e` alone)?

In brief I want to be able to pass the following 2 syntax:

1. `-e <boolean> (value is based from the value passed)`
2. `-e (will make the value of variable` enable_value `became true)`

I also have read this and it does not related to what I asked:

[how to make an argument optional in getopt bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29222495/how-to-make-an-argument-optional-in-getopt-bash)

Comment: Why aren't you using `getopts` in the `while` loop that processes arguments?

Comment: @Barmar didn't I use while loop for that ?

Comment: No, I mean something like `while getopts ...; do`

Comment: I saw your new edit from `getopt` to `getopts`. The reason I use `getopt` as opposed from `getopts` is because I want to have a long options that is easier to implement. How do you use getopt to process arguments in while loop. I dont get it as I think it was done.

Comment: Options that take optional arguments are defined using *two* colons, i.e., `e::` instead of `e:`. (I'm not entirely sure *how* you get either an explicit argument or a default; it seems to depend on which *mode* you are using to parse the arguments.)

Comment: (It looks like you simply have to remember that `-e` was used, then look after `--` to see which, if any, argument was provided, rather than being as simple as using `$2`.)

Comment: I try to print all the arguments using `e::` but it returns nothing. On your second comment, I think I understand what you mean, but I think it is complicated as I need to care about the positional of the argument. Not sure how to implement that.

Comment: See [ComplexOptionParsing](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ComplexOptionParsing) on the Wooledge wiki (home of the #bash IRC channel) for a discussion of things they consider bad ideas, and [BashFAQ #35](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/035) for discussion of the approaches they consider good ideas. Note that `getopt` is in the former category.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Been using it many months, it's time to move into getopts? I used to read a reason why I did not want to use getopts. I will look into it. Thanks ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please c.f. [Unable to read bash shell script arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73969698/unable-to-read-bash-shell-script-arguments/73974854#73974854)

If you have even one more than just that one `-e` option, then this is a near-untenable situation, and your users will hate you.

I usually try to set required defaults silently in my code with lines like

```
: ${e:=false}
```

That way, if not set, it gets a sane default.  If inherited, exported, set on the CLI (etc) then it uses whatever value is present.

With the following code -

```
$: cat tst
#! /bin/bash

declare x
while getopts "xe" o
do case "$o" in
   x) x=1; echo "X is set";;
   e) if [[ -n "${e:-}" ]]
      then echo >&2 "e inherited value '$e', cannot set"; exit 1
      else e=true; echo "E set to $e"
      fi ;;
   [?]) echo "oops"; exit ;;
   esac
done
: ${e:=false}

declare -p x e
```

Consider the following cases -

```
$: ./tst                         # NO ARGUMENTS
declare -- x
declare -- e="false"

$: ./tst -x                      # one arg, not -e
X is set
declare -- x="1"
declare -- e="false"

$: ./tst -e                      # one arg, -e
E set to true
declare -- x
declare -- e="true"

$: ./tst -ex                     # both args, empty
E set to true
X is set
declare -- x="1"
declare -- e="true"

$: ./tst -f                      # invalid argument
./tst: illegal option -- f
oops

$: e=foo ./tst                   # no args, e inherited/exported/pre-set
declare -- x
declare -x e="foo"

$: e=foo ./tst -x                # one non -e arg, e inherited/exported/pre-set
X is set
declare -- x="1"
declare -x e="foo"
```

## With an export -

```
$: export e=foo

$: ./tst -x                      # letting the export stand
X is set
declare -- x="1"
declare -x e="foo"

$: e= ./tst -x                   # override/unset
X is set
declare -- x="1"
declare -x e="false"
```

expicit overrides -

```
$: e=bar ./tst                   # uses bar
declare -- x
declare -x e="bar"

$: e=bar ./tst -x                # same
X is set
declare -- x="1"
declare -x e="bar"

$: e= ./tst -x -e                # override/unset, then set internal true
X is set
E set to true
declare -- x="1"
declare -x e="true"
```

still doesn't allow both, either way.

```
$: ./tst -x -e                   # trying to set, didn't override export
X is set
e inherited value 'foo', cannot set

$: e=bar ./tst -x -e             # override, but set, can't use -e
X is set
e inherited value 'bar', cannot set
```

## (End of export assumptions...)

These all work well enough, but when you start trying to use an optional argument -

```
$: ./tst -e foo                  # e: *requires*, e w/o : *ignores*
E set to true
declare -- x
declare -- e="true"

$: e=foo ./tst -e bar            # e: *requires*, e w/o : *ignores*
e inherited value 'foo', cannot set

$: e=foo ./tst -ex               # e: *requires*, e w/o : *ignores*
e inherited value 'foo', cannot set
```

and of course,

```
$: ./tst -x -efoo
X is set
E set to true
./tst: illegal option -- f
oops
```

Like most programs, you can stack args, but this blows up as soon as it doesn't recognize one as a boolean option.

Changing

```
while getopts "xe" o
```

to

```
while getopts "xe:" o # just adding the colon
```

requires we also change

```
  else e=true; echo "E set to $e"
```

to

```
  else e=$OPTARG; echo "E set to $e"
```

This gives -

```
$: ./tst                         # same
declare -- x
declare -- e="false"

$: ./tst -x                      # same
X is set
declare -- x="1"
declare -- e="false"

$: ./tst -e foo                  # works like a champ...
E set to foo
declare -- x
declare -- e="foo"
```

and (almost surprisingly), these work...

```
$: ./tst -efoo
E set to foo
declare -- x
declare -- e="foo"

$: ./tst -x -efoo                # I hate this
X is set
E set to foo
declare -- x="1"
declare -- e="foo"

$: ./tst -efoo -x
E set to foo
X is set
declare -- x="1"
declare -- e="foo"
```

but

```
$:  ./tst -e
./tst: option requires an argument -- e
oops
```

While the `-e` can be omitted, if you do use it, the argument isn't "optional" *at all*.

*AND* -

```
$: ./tst -e -x                   # this one really tangles users.
E set to -x
declare -- x
declare -- e="-x"
```

---

## Don't use getopt

***If*** that's why you are using `getopt` instead of `getopts`, I recommend finding another way.
You *can* make `getopt` work - sort of... but don't.

Looking at it -
c.f. https://ss64.com/osx/getopt.html

```
$: cat tst
#! /bin/bash
short_opts="xe::"
options=$(getopt -o "${short_opts}" -- "$@")
if (($?))
then echo "Invalid option"
     exit 1
fi
set -- ${options} # no eval and no quotes - which will eventually cause problems
declare x
while [[ -n "$1" ]]
do case "$1" in
   -x) x=1; echo "X is set";;
   -e) if [[ -n "${e:-}" ]]
       then echo >&2 "e inherited value '$e', cannot set"; exit 1
       fi
       if [[ -n "$2" ]]
       then e="$2"; shift
       else e=true
       fi ;;
   --) shift; break;;
   -*) echo "oops"; exit ;;
   esac
   shift
done
: ${e:=false}

declare -p x e
```

This feels like a lot of hackery to me. In use:

```
$: ./tst                         # ok
declare -- x
declare -- e="false"

$: ./tst -x                      # ok
X is set
declare -- x="1"
declare -- e="false"

$: ./tst -efoo                   # ugh... works, but who does this?
declare -- x
declare -- e="foo"

$: ./tst -xefoo                  # works... but very confusing
X is set
declare -- x="1"
declare -- e="foo"

$: ./tst -x -efoo                # works, still ugly
X is set
declare -- x="1"
declare -- e="foo"

$: ./tst -efoo -x                # works, but one habitual space breaks
X is set
declare -- x="1"
declare -- e="foo"
```

but these don't work because the space after the `-e` is *not allowed*.

```
$: ./tst -x -e foo               # e is '', foo is silently IGNORED...
X is set
declare -- x="1"
declare -- e="''"

$: ./tst -e foo -x               # SAME
X is set
declare -- x="1"
declare -- e="''"
```

With no arg -

```
$ ./tst -e                       # oops, still empty e
declare -- x
declare -- e="''"

$: ./tst -e -x                   # effectively same again
X is set
declare -- x="1"
declare -- e="''"
```

So basically, still not optional...
And if you expect stacking, this one is bad enough...

```
$: ./tst -xe
X is set
declare -- x="1"
declare -- e="''"
```

but *THIS* guy...

```
$: ./tst -ex           # doesn't set x - assigns the x to e
declare -- x
declare -- e="'x'"
```

## final observations

If you just want optional...

```
$: cat tst
#! /bin/bash
declare x e
: ${e:=false}          # set a default
declare -p x e

$: ./tst             
declare -- x
declare -- e="false"

$: x=foo ./tst           
declare -x x="foo"
declare -- e="false"

$: x=2 e=true ./tst
declare -x x="2"
declare -x e="true"
```

No parsing. Plenty of options for testing.

Good luck.

Comment: I'm testing yours but doesn't seems like my geopt version cameout the same output like urs. On the 3rd test `./tst -e` i got this output `declare -- x
declare -- e="''"` .

Comment: I'm trying to undertand that if the enchanced getopt would have issue on what you said here.

Comment: Sorry, editing error. Make more sense now?

Comment: The one that you mention don't work `./tst -x -e foo` is actually working for me. Same thing like `./tst -e foo -x` (I got the correct output). and it is working because I changed `xe::` to `xe:` because I don't know why did you put extra `:` there. My first question is why do you have the double colon at the end like this xe:: and not this xe:

Comment: [getopt](https://ss64.com/osx/getopt.html) vs [getopts](https://ss64.com/bash/getopts.html). Notice how they are used completely differently in the respective versions of the scripts. `getopt` "allows" an *optional* argument if you use two colons, which is really a bad design. `getopts` does not.